# Split The body in Apache camel and Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, split, apache-camel

I have a process like this to send some queries by body to the next process:

```
.process(exchange -> {
   List<GlossaryDTOResponse[]> glossaries = exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
   
   List<String> queries = new ArrayList<>();

   queries.add("countries=AF&planttypes=AA&status=DD&language=en-EN&pagesize=1");
   queries.add("countries=BF&planttypes=AA&status=DB&language=en-EN&pagesize=1");
   
   List<ActivityIssuesDTO> responses = new ArrayList<>();

   // just to send an empity response array to create the final result
   Util.setProperty(exchange, "response", responses);

   exchange.getIn().setBody(queries);
})
```

And then i split the body to read each body element:

```
.split(body())
```

Then i read the body in each element and send it by HTTP query to a microservice:

```
.process(exchange -> {
   List<GlossaryDTOResponse>  glossaryDTOResponses = exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
   List<ActivityIssuesDTO> responses = exchange.getProperty("response", List.class);

   Util.setProperty(exchange, "response", responses);
   exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, glossaryDTOResponses.get(0));
})
.toD(serviceUtils.getActivityEndpoint() + ServiceUtils.ACTIVITIES + Util.BRIDGE_ENDPOINT)
.unmarshal().json(ActivityIssuesDTO.class)
```

In this process i have my final response in activityIssuesDTO and i send it with body.

```
.process(exchange -> {
   ActivityIssuesDTO activityIssuesDTO = exchange.getIn().getBody(ActivityIssuesDTO.class);     
   List<ActivityIssuesDTO> activityIssuesDTOs = exchange.getProperty("response", List.class);
   activityIssuesDTOs.add(activityIssuesDTO);
                
   exchange.getIn().setBody(activityIssuesDTOs);
})
.marshal().json();
```

The problem is that i can't see my response and can't marshal it.

Thank you.

I removed the split and for one item(query) it's ok and i can see my response but for many query i can't see my response.

I tried it also with static array and it's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood it in each Split we need also an aggregator to aggregation our message to continue the process and i resolved it by creating an aggregator and put create the finale result inside my aggregator this result is coming from my micro service.

this is the final result:

```
.split(body()) 
   .aggregationStrategy(new ActivityAggregator())
   .streaming()
   .to(direct(GET_QUERY_FINAL))
   .end()
```

and this is my internal route:

```
from(direct(GET_QUERY_FINAL))
   .log("getting the query and send to activity ms")
   .process(exchange -> {
      String queries = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
      List<ActivityIssuesDTO> response = exchange.getProperty("response", List.class);
      Util.setProperty(exchange, "response", response);
      exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, queries);
     })
.toD(serviceUtils.getActivityEndpoint() + ServiceUtils.ACTIVITIES + Util.BRIDGE_ENDPOINT)
.unmarshal().json(ActivityIssuesDTO.class);
```

and inside my aggregator i just put the final result inside my new array.

Thanks.